# Pipeline Jenkins, what's the correct way to use variables to use

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We've just moved from using the buildflow plugin to pipeline as buildflow was deprecated & the recommendation was to move onto pipeline when possible.

Our previous build flow looked like this:

```
def rioBranchName = params["rioBranch"]
def restBranchName = params["restBranch"]
def deployServer =  params["deploymentServer"]
def tagNumber = build.number
def automationBuild

build( "Restart Tomcat", deploymentServers: deployServer)

parallel (
  { build( "Rio", branch: rioBranchName, deploymentServer: deployServer, extraTasks:"multiReDeploy", gradleSwitches: "--settings-file packageSettings.gradle") },
  { build( "REST - Smoke Tests", branch: restBranchName,  deploymentServer: deployServer, extraTasks:"multiReDeploy") }, 
  { automationBuild = build( "Rio Automation", branch: rioBranchName) }
)


build("Restart Tomcat", deploymentServers: deployServer)

build("SCTM Trigger - Develop - Smoke", ,  automationTestBuildNumber: automationBuild.build.number)
```

and I've tried to convert this into a pipeline flow.

```
def automationBuild

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            steps {
                parallel buildAtlas: {
                     build job: 'Rio', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: params["rioBranch"])]
                }, buildRest: {
                    build job: 'REST - Smoke Tests', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', params["restBranch"])]
                }, buildAutomation: {
                    automationBuild = build job: 'Rio Automation', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: params["rioBranch"])]
                },
                failFast: false
            }
        }
        stage('Test commit'){
            steps {
                build job: 'Restart Tomcat', parameters: [string(name: 'deploymentServers', value: params["deploymentServer"])]
                build job: 'SCTM Trigger - Develop - Smoke', parameters: [string(name: 'automationTestBuildNumber', value: automationBuild.build.number)]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I consistently get the error.

```
WorkflowScript: 11: Expected a step @ line 11, column 6.
def automationBuild = build job: 'Rio Automation', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: params["rioBranch"])]
```

What is the new correct way to get the version number of the build RioAutomation that was just triggered.

Comment: Try wrapping it an a `steps { ... }`

Comment: Added `buildAutomation: {
        steps {
           automationBuild = build job: 'Rio Automation', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: params["rioBranch"])] 
        }
    },` & got the same error is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. And what if you declare the `automationBuild` inside the `pipeline { }`

Comment: Can you post how the generated pipeline file looks like?

Comment: So here's a paste bin of those changes. https://pastebin.com/gYDNxsgK It's still throwing a similar error & another. org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2: Not a valid section definition: "def automationBuild". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 2, column 5.
       def automationBuild
       ^

WorkflowScript: 13: Expected a step @ line 13, column 10.
            automationBuild = build job: 'Rio Automation', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: params["rioBranch"])]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the non-step assignment instruction in a `script` block to get it to [lint/validate](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter) clean:

```
def rioBranchName = params["rioBranch"]
def restBranchName = params["restBranch"]
def deployServer =  params["deploymentServer"]
def tagNumber = build.number
def automationBuild

build( "Restart Tomcat", deploymentServers: deployServer)

parallel (
  { build( "Rio", branch: rioBranchName, deploymentServer: deployServer, extraTasks:"multiReDeploy", gradleSwitches: "--settings-file packageSettings.gradle") },
  { build( "REST - Smoke Tests", branch: restBranchName,  deploymentServer: deployServer, extraTasks:"multiReDeploy") }, 
  { 
    script {
      automationBuild = build( "Rio Automation", branch: rioBranchName)
    }
  }
)


build("Restart Tomcat", deploymentServers: deployServer)

build("SCTM Trigger - Develop - Smoke", ,  automationTestBuildNumber: automationBuild.build.number)
```

Note that `script` let's your run pretty much any groovy code you can run in a scripted pipeline inside a declarative pipeline step.

Comment: This put me on the right track... script allowed me to run the builds setting the variable. As you said it allows you to run almost any groovy code. I'll accept this for now & tomorrow will add the extra logic needed to get this to work completely.